# Label not displaying in JQuery remote success callback

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-validate

I want to display a label after a remote JQuery validate success callback is made. But it doesn't seem to be executing the code.

Here is my code.

```js
$('#Location').rules("add", {
  required: true,
  //minlength: 5,
  maxlength: 5,
  messages: {
    required: "Required input",
    minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please, {0} characters are necessary"),
    maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please, {0} characters are necessary"),
    remote: jQuery.validator.format("Could not locate zip code")
  },
  remote: {
    url: "CheckLocation",
    type: "post",
    data: {
      Location: function() {
        return $('#Location').val();
      },
      success: function(data) {
        //console.log(data);
        $('#locationSuccess').attr('display', ''); // not working
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<label id="locationSuccess" style="color: green; display: none">ahh, Somewhere</label>
```

Comment: Use `$('#locationSuccess').show();`

Comment: It's not working because `display` is not an `attribute`; it's a CSS property.  Try `.css()` instead of `.attr()`.

Comment: Again, please do not use the Code Snippets feature for any code that will not run within this page.  Removed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery .show() method

```
$('#locationSuccess').show();
```

or .css()

```
$('#locationSuccess').css('display', '');
```